# UK tourist visa refused , any idea?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

[image: I have been refused UK visa twice]

I didn't demonstrate any significant strong personal ties to my home country.

Comment: You seem to understand the refusal. What is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Answer (score 0):

You were refused entry because you didn't demonstrate any significant strong personal ties to your home country.

They expect you to overstay and seek employment. Likely, enrollment in universities similar to yours has been a 'ticket' to a visa by people seeking to overstay.